# spyOn isDevMode() in Angular 6+ Unit Tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My code includes an `if` block like this

Service:

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

export class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  methodToTest(): {
    if (!isDevMode()) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      doSomethingDifferentInDevMode();
    }
  }
}
```

my-service.spec.ts (the relevant lines only):

```
it('should run doSomething() when isDevMode() returns false', () => {
  // what should i do here to mock a false value return for isDevMode() ?
  expect(doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

How do i spyOn the `isDevMode()` to make it return false for this single Angular unit test so that i may test that `doSomething()` is called?

Comment: How and where is isDevMode() defined. Post the relevant code.

Comment: Wrap the call into a service method, inject the service, and spy on the service method in your test.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start by wrapping this function into a service:

```
import { isDevMode, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DevModeService {
  constructor() {}

  isDevMode() {
    return isDevMode();
  }
}
```

Then you can inject this service wherever you want, as you would do with any other service:

```
import { DevModeService } from 'dev-mode.service';

export class MyService {
  constructor(private devModeService: DevModeService) {}

  methodToTest(): {
    if (!this.devModeService.isDevMode()) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  }
}
```

And you can then spy on the DevModeService when testing MyService, like you would do with any other dependency:

```
it('should do something when in dev mode') {
  const devModeService = TestBed.inject(DevModeService);
  spyOn(devModeService, 'isDevMode').and.returnValue(true);

  const myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  myService.methodToTest();
  // ...
}

it('should do something else when in prod mode') {
  const devModeService = TestBed.inject(DevModeService);
  spyOn(devModeService, 'isDevMode').and.returnValue(false);

  const myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  myService.methodToTest();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is in the comments.  Thanks @JBNizet.

```
// dev-mode-service.ts

import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

export class DevModeService {
  constructor() {}

  isDevMode(): {
    return isDevMode();
  }
}


// MyService.ts

import { isDevMode } from 'dev-mode-service';

export class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  methodToTest(): {
    if (!isDevMode()) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      doSomethingDifferentInDevMode();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I'm using is the following

```js
import { enableProdMode, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
declare const global: any;

describe('teststing IsDevMode', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        /**
         * We must reset the devmode to true before each test, as it is the default non prod state
         *
         */
        global['ngDevMode'] = true;
    });

    it('should be true in tests', () => {
        expect(isDevMode()).toBe(true);
    });
    it('should be false for prod using ngInternals', () => {
        enableProdMode();
        expect(isDevMode()).toBe(false);
    });
    it('should be false for prod', () => {
        global['ngDevMode'] = false;
        expect(isDevMode()).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

So basically we are overwriting the global variable used for checking if the project is in devMode. You can find out how the internals work here: [AngularGitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ad045efd4b1565e01c14399998143538ebfbfd99/packages/core/src/util/is_dev_mode.ts)